# Eloquent firstOrNew() query not recognizing parameters passed to it

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to create a set of bogus users, using random string names, which I will later use the IDs for. I am running into an error where it isn't recognizing some of the variables I pass through. Below is my code:

```
        $password = bcrypt($this->generateRandomString(15));

        $user = User::firstOrNew([
            'email' => ($firstName . '@company.com'),
            'password' => $password,
            'username' => $username,
            'firstname' => $firstName,
            'lastname' => $lastName,
        ]);
        $user->save();
        $userIds[] = $user->id;
```

I am using firstOrNew just in case a user with that random username has been already entered, in which case I'll just use its ID.

I know that `$username`, `$firstName`, and `$lastName` all have data in those objects through testing, but for whatever reason, I get an error regarding a duplicate error on `'username'` because it believes that field is empty (''), even though I know my variable is not.

In other words, the SQL statement is only passing on the email and the password, and not the other three variables. Any thoughts?

---

Error message:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                               
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'Ollie@positivelearning.com' for key 'users_email_unique' (SQL: insert into  
`users` (`email`, `password`, `username`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Ollie@positivelearning.com, y$rx8R0N5dVAibjpXxV0OF4uGGb7lradsl2xME  
20ymMvv2YPaUWv3oq, olliepritsak, 2016-07-14 18:10:10, 2016-07-14 18:10:10))  

[PDOException]                                                                                            
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'users_username_unique'
```

Comment: What's the $username value?

Comment: ^ Is this a fillable field on your model?

Comment: *Please keep your hands off Enter!*

Comment: Please find something better to complain about. @revo

Comment: @MikeBarwick I didn't have `username` included as fillable on my model. A careless mistake. Thank you!

Comment: *I would, if I could.* @MikeBarwick

Comment: lol keep browsing posts...I'm sure you'll find something else to troll :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so based on the error (your original error posted)...doesn't look like you're passing the following values, `'username' => $username, 'firstname' => $firstName, 'lastname' => $lastName,`...

Make sure in your `User` model, you have these under `fillable`, like so:

```
protected $fillable = [
    ...
    'username',
    'firstname',
    'lastname',
];
```

I think this is where your problem is stemming from.

Comment: Yep this was exactly it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem! I've made this mistake a hundred times over.

Answer (score 1):

Method `firstOrNew()` is attempting to locate a database record using all the given column / value pairs. You should only use the attributes that make an unique key, like email, for instance.

Then you will want to check for the model's `exists` property to fill in the remaining fields if the model is new (`exists` is false) and save it.